Vault kv patch with multiple key-value pairs
I want to execute the following code in jenkins pipeline
 def updateFunction= "vault kv patch -namespace=namespace "
                        updateFunction += "-mount=mount "
                        updateFunction += "key1=$key1"
                        updateFunction += "key2=$key2"

  sh updateFunction

But only the first key is patched and the second part throws
script.sh.copy: line 2: key2=key2: not found 
The only way it works it if I split it in two but this way I have two new versions instead of 1

There isn't enough information about the source of key1, but I bet it has a new line character at the end. Try trimming it and adding a trailing space:
def updateFunction= "vault kv patch -namespace=namespace "
updateFunction += "-mount=mount "
updateFunction += "key1=${key1.trim()} "
updateFunction += "key2=$key2"

Generally speaking building a script like that is asking for trouble. Unless you are absolutely sure your values are [0-9a-zA-Z]+ you would need to think about escaping them. And that's a pretty deep rabbit hole if you want to do it correctly. I would replace it with:
withEnv([
    "key1=$key1",
    "key2=$key2",
]) {
    sh script: '''
        vault kv patch -namespace=namespace -mount=mount key1="$key1" key2="$key2"
    '''
}

Notice ''' - they ensure that parameter expansion is happening in the shell, not in groovy.

Basically I am trying to have like a AES key rotation pipeline, which overwrites the keys, keys are hex so I think there is no problem with the regEx, I will test now with your proposal!

You were correct when openssl is used to generate the key there is a trailing new line, your solution solved my problem!
